# I want the picture box to move every second to the right by one place

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Here is where I have tried to implement the code to change the location of the picture box but it doesn't seem to be working, I want the picture to move to the right:

```
Public Class Form1
  Dim mypicturebox As New PictureBox
  Dim randval As Integer

  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.Text = "hello " & TextBox1.Text
    Timer1.Enabled = True
  End Sub
    
  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Interval = 2000
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    mypicturebox.Location = New Point(mypicturebox.Location.X + 5, mypicturebox.Location.Y + 5)
  End Sub

  Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label1.Font = New Font(Label1.Font.FontFamily, Label1.Font.Size + 
    mypicturebox.Location = New Point(mypicturebox.Location.X + 5, mypicturebox.Location.Y)
  End Sub  
End Class
```

Comment: You have nothing random going on in your code.

Comment: i want it to move to the right by one space every clock tick

Comment: Your code should work.  Not sure what's going on with your incomplete `Label1.Font = ` code in your Tick event.  It doesn't belong there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your current Timer handler - if the Timer is actually firing - is just going to drift your PictureBox off to the right by 5px each Timer period.

If you want a random position you need a way to get a random number. `Random` is your best bet.

You also need to ensure that the generated random position is "valid" for both the size of your screen and the size of the PictureBox otherwise the PictureBox might be either entirely invisible (off screen) or partially visible.

Here's some basic code to get two random numbers between -100 and 100 to get you started:

```
Dim myRand As Random = New Random(Now.Second)
Dim newX As Integer = myRand.Next(-100, 100)
Dim newY As Integer = myRand.Next(-100, 100)
```

(`Now.Second` seeds the generation of `myRandom` so that it should generate different starting numbers each time.)

Then you can use these as your PictureBox location points:

```
mypicturebox.Location = New Point(newX, newY)
```

Play around with limiting your locations and you should get what you want.

**UPDATE**

Ok, scrap all that as you've changed your requirement description ...

Just add whatever offset you need to your `X` position and you're done, provided your Timer is firing. You still need to watch your screen limits.

Comment: You can omit the `Now.Second` as the [Random Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Random__ctor) already does this for you.  Also, either move that declaration out to FORM LEVEL, or change `Dim` to [Static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/static) so that you don't create a new Random instance for each `Tick()`.